# Auto Increment Index SQL Server, Oracle DB and MySQL with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, innodb, oracle12c

MySQL with InnoDB engine has the "feature" of keeping indexes of autoincrement columns on RAM and it is updated each time the service starts. This leads to possible duplicate ids when you delete rows at the bottom of the table, restart the MySQL service and then you insert a new row, its id will be duplicated. For example:

1.- We have this:

```
ID   | Name
-------------
1    |'John'
2    |'Paul'
3    |'Ringo'
4    |'George'
```

2.- We delete row with id=4

```
ID   | Name
-------------
1    |'John'
2    |'Paul'
3    |'Ringo'
```

We restart MySQL and insert a new row

```
ID   | Name
-------------
1    |'John'
2    |'Paul'
3    |'Ringo'
4    |'Pete'
```

So, my question is: SQL Server and Oracle DB have a similar behavior or the final result on them is like the following table:

```
ID   | Name
-------------
1    |'John'
2    |'Paul'
3    |'Ringo'
5    |'Pete'
```

In other words, is the behavior of SQL Server and Oracle DB  the same as MySQL with InnoDB or it keeps the las index of the auto_increment columns even after reset so there is no posible duplicate entries?

Comment: What are you actually asking? And why is the question tagged with _oracle12c_?

Comment: From my experience SQL Server maintains the auto increment. It will, by default, keep increasing the auto increment value and wont use a previously inserted one just like your final table

Comment: @bub What I am asking is if the behavior of SQL Server and Oracle DB is the same as MySQL with InnoDB or it keeps the las index of the auto_increment columns even after reset so there is no posible duplicate entries.

Comment: Think about it from a different direction. Regardless of the auto increment value, the index value will still be based on the records added. your next auto increment value might be 10, but if you only have 4 rows then you will only have 4 index values. Nothing says that auto increment values have to match index positions.

Comment: Oracle is not support autoincrement column. Instead Oracle use "sequence". Values generated by "sequence" independent on any table data and not duplicate

Comment: @Takarii you are right. However, sometimes our clients make audits on the information and when entries are deleted  and the server is restarted this could lead to confusion or bad interpretation. So I am asking this question to get the right behavior on each DB.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your comment.

Comment: if records are deleted, then the server logs said deletion in its logfile. Why would a client audit your indexes? if they have issues with missing records, then they should be looking at logfiles, not index tables. Also note, this is a good arguement  for why deleting records is generally not a good idea until they are no longer required for any kind of audit purpose.

Comment: @Takarii I think you are right. Nothing to say. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB guarantees uniqueness at any moment.  It does not guarantee against delete + restart + insert reusing a number.  If your app expects that, you are expecting more than it delivers.

There are other cases where InnoDB *may* act differently.  Consider a multi-row `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, etc.  InnoDB, by default (there is a setting to change this) will pre-assign the desired number of rows.  But a `ROLLBACK`, dup key, etc will not return the unused numbers to the pool (except in the restart situation you mentioned).

If the auditors are looking in the log, the either need to notice the delete, or demand that you change your code to avoid ever reusing an id.  A "sequence" can be simulated if you really need it.

Comment: BTW, you aren't the first to complain:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199&thanks=3&notify=199

Comment: _Breaking news:_ MySQL version 8.0 provides a way to avoid reuse of a number after restart.